# Issue with Constructors with templates

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Given below are is my cpp code. I have written both declaration and definition in same cpp file because there are templates in this code and I got some errors when I had two separate files for header and code. so I had to write everything in same file. Still, I have errors with constructor declaration and definition.
Why is this throwing the below error, is there something which am missing.

```
template<class T>
class Linklist
{
public:
Linklist();
Linklist(Linklist<T> & a);
~Linklist();
}     
template<class T>
Linklist<T>::Linklist()
{
}
template<class T>
Linklist::Linklist(Linklist<T> & a) 
{
}
```

Error C2244: 'Linklist::{ctor}' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration         definition
        'Linklist::Linklist(Linklist &)'          existing declarations
          'Linklist::Linklist(Linklist &)'
          'Linklist::Linklist(void)'

Comment: Can't reproduce after fixing some small typos: http://ideone.com/gs312h Put a `;` after class declaration and change copy cconstructor definition:  `Linklist<T>::Linklist(Linklist<T> & a) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original:

```
template<class T>
Linklist::Linklist(Linklist<T> & a) // You forgot something here... see below
{
}
```

Fixed:

```
template<class T>
Linklist<T>::Linklist(Linklist<T> & a) // <T> is what was missing.
{
}
```

And class declarations end with a `;`, too.